# Есть ли способ разместить камеру отталкиваясь от User Perspective(Blender)?

Tags: blender

Есть навязчивая проблема - постановка камеры так, чтобы кадр смотрелся хорошо.
Могу ли я сначала выставить ракурс в самом редакторе(UserPerspective или же Object mode), а потом на моих же координатах "*заспавнить камеру*"?

Скажем, я летаю по редактору, могу что то добавить, изменить и т.д. и я в один момент захотел поставить камеру туда, куда я смотрю.
Возможно ли такое? Что я могу сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Нажмите - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num 0</kbd>.